# Restricting fb:recommendations-bar suggestions to a subdirectory within a domain

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, xfbml, facebook-recommendations

Is there a way to restrict `<fb:recommendations-bar>` suggestions to a subdirectory within a domain? As a university club, we are given a subdirectory to use within the same domain space as all the other campus groups. But we would like to keep recommend-box suggestions within our own website, which resides within our campus-group subdirectory. To recommend pages outside our web space is counterproductive.

Comment: There is a `site`parameter for the plugin, put that want’s a list of domains, not full HTTP addresses including paths. Could you maybe get a _subdomain_ from your server’s admin to provide access to your club page, instead of just the subdirectory? Then it should be easy using said parameter.

Comment: It's possible to get a special subdomain defined for a university club (virtual hosting), but that costs more. We're trying to save money.